# Механизм (способ воплощения) игрового поля в браузере

Tags: html, разработка-игр

Хочу перевести настольную игру в электронный вид. Должна получиться браузерная игра на несколько человек. Поле игры расчерчено на квадраты, по которым ходят игроки.

Как лучше реализовать игровое поле?

Рассматривал несколько вариантов. Первый(достаточно традиционный) - прибегнуть к флешу. Но, по некоторым причинам, отказался от этого варианта. Второй(в лоб) - сделать таблицу в HTML, и плясать от этого. Этот вариант нравится тем, что все достаточно просто реализуемо.

Есть ли еще какие-нибудь способы? Советы по HTML5?

Comment: рисовать на канвасе.

Comment: я думал над этим. А какие преимущества? Как определять клики по клеткам?

Comment: Таблицы/div'ы/canvas без разницы. Делайте на том что вам ближе и что вы знаете.

Comment: ловишь клик по канвасу: onclick='return onClick (event)' в атрибутах тега, описываешь function onClick (args) в скрипте и там ловишь координаты клика и вычисляешь какая клетка находится под ними.